# Forcing a delegate method to be called

Tags: cocoa, delegates, nsnotificationcenter, nssplitview

I have a delegate method of an `NSSplitView` like this:

```
- (void)splitViewWillResizeSubviews:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"RESIZE!");
}
```

This method is called whenever I drag a divider, so it registered properly. I would like to call this from another object, and was thinking to use this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NSSplitViewWillResizeSubviewsNotification object:self];
```

According to the Apple docs, this is the notification that should be sent to call the delegate method. However, it does not work. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you wanting to expose the implementation of `splitViewWillResizeSubviews` to another class? Or are you looking to get an additional notification from the NSSplitView in another class?

Comment: I would like to notify the delegate manually, from another object, ie without the user resizing the splitview sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just invoke the method manually

```
NSSplitView * yourSplitView; //Get reference to your splitview
id yourSplitViewDelegate = [yourSplitView delegate];
[yourSplitViewDelegate splitViewWillResizeSubviews:nil];//Optionally create the NSNotification with relevant data
```

If you really want to go through notification center, make sure `self` in your question is the NSSplitView.

```
NSSplitView * yourSplitView; //Get reference to your splitview
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NSSplitViewWillResizeSubviewsNotification object:yourSplitView];
```

Comment: I'd like to call the `splitViewWillResizeSubviews` from the viewcontroller of one of the subviews. I don't have an elegant reference to the splitView itself from there (although I could always "manually" pass it along. I would like to avoid the latter, but if necessary, I guess directly invoking the method would be possible.

Comment: Regarding the second option: why would the `self` in my question need to be the splitView? `- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender`; I am not experienced at all with notifications, but should the sender not be the class from which I post the notification?

Comment: the `notificationSender` is the class *sending* the notification, not the class who receives it. The NSNotificationCenter manages which classes to send the notifications to.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to manually register the delegate class for the `NSSplitViewWillResizeSubviewsNotification` notifications!

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(splitViewWillResizeSubviews:)
                                                 name:NSSplitViewWillResizeSubviewsNotification
                                               object:vc];
```

where vc is the viewcontroller that should be sending the notifications.

This is unexpected behavior (to me), since an `<NSSplitViewDelegate>` is expected to register automatically for `NSSplitView...` notifications.